# How to fit all the widgets together using grid Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to fit all widget, I have tree frames:

First frame:
 Have a label (that need to have some name with a big letter size)
 A custom combobox to change the value of the label if nedded
 A button to make the selection of the combobox

Second frame:
 Have a treeview with some information that when I make a clic in one row another treeview appears in the 3rd frame. This treeview have occupy all the frame

Third frame:
 Have three columns:
  The first one have two rows:
   Fist row two buttons add and remove, that have occupy all the row.
   Second row a treeview that have occupy all it space. This treeview appears when click a row in the first treeview, how can I show the empty treeview and fill in when click the row. The function is OnDoubleClick
  The second column:
   Have two buttons that have to be in the center of the rows.
  The third column:
   Same as the first but with other treeview.

Here is an image of what i want to achive:

[image]

Comment: Do you really need all that code to duplicate your problem? That's a lot of code. Try to reduce it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is too broad as written. A question should ask about one specific problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for your reply, my question is about how to fit all the widgets together. I'm going to reduce the code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to rewrite your whole program because that's a lot of code, but I'll explain the way I would approach the problem. Tkinter layout is really simple if you are methodical and organized, and try to solve only one problem at a time.

### Main layout

First, you seem to have three main sections: a toolbar across the top, a middle section with a treeview, and a bottom section with a whole bunch of stuff. So, first thing I would do is create three frames, one for each section. Then, I would use `pack` like this:

```
toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
bottom.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False)
```

- I don't know if that third section should expand or not. It's not clear what sort of behavior you expect when the user resizes the window.

### Toolbar layout

This one is very straight-forward. It's three widgets spread equally. You can use `pack` or `grid`, either will work just fine.

### Main layout

This just has a treeview, or maybe a treeview with scrollbars? Again, `pack` or `grid` works just fine with such a simple layout.

### Bottom

This one appears to be made up of three sections: a left section, a middle section, and a right section. Like with the main layout, I would start by creating three frames, all as children of the "bottom" frame created earlier. Then, I would again use `pack` since it's a simple horizontal layout:

```
left.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
middle.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
right.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

By setting `expand=True` to the left and right sides, if the window grows or shrinks, these will grow or shrink too while the middle section stays its natural size.

#### Bottom-left and Bottom-right

Both of these look identical. It looks like the easiest thing to do would be to create the widgets (ie: no more frames), and then use `grid` to lay them out. Though, if by "buttons" you mean you could have several, you could create a frame for the buttons so that you can more easily pack all the buttons from left to right.

#### Bottom-center

You can create buttons that are a child of this frame, and use either `grid` or `pack`.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Oakley for your answer, helps me a lot. I have another couple of question, first when I can use grid and pack together, second is ok to create a class MainWindow(Frame): and inside use functions to separate the differents widget in his corresponding frames?

Comment: @diego: You can use both `grid` and `pack` in the same application, you just can't use them both for widgets that have the same parent. For the second question: yes.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Oakley, your answer help me a lot to order my self to make this gui.